# Please help with a dictionary comprehension in LINQ, C#

Tags: linq, dictionary, list-comprehension

Python's equivalent of what I want is:

```
>>> #C#: Dictionary<int, string> tempDict = ...
>>> tempDict = {i : str(i) for i in range(200000)}
>>> tempDict[5]
'5'
>>>
```

The example is a bit simplified, but I can modify it myself; do not want to bother you with details of proprietary classes.

Got it:

```
var y = (from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 20000) select Guid.NewGuid()).ToDictionary(g=>g, g=>new MyObj(g))
```

Comment: perhaps write what you want in text for us who does not know python :)

Comment: A dictionary such as 1:'1', 2:'2', etc.
However, my original requirement has changed a bit. I actually need to create a dict of guid : object where ... to create an object, I must have a guid. With a normal loop I would use a temp variable. I do not think that lambdas allow me to do the same. Let me know if that is not the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 200000).ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.ToString())
```

maybe?

Comment: Thank you. Now ... what if I wanted to not use an index at all? The key must be a Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid(), and a value is ... say guid.ToString() or myFunc(guid) - the point is that A) Guids are given to me by the system, B) the value depends on the key (guid). Would it make sense to get a generator of guids and then feed it into a dict? I know that one-liners can get ugly, but I am learning LINQ and am curious if it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I want something like Enumerable.Repeat<Guid>( () => Guid.NewGuid(), 200000) except that Repeat does not take a lambda but a value. Also, I do not want to use an intermediate ToList - I want to keep stuff as IEnumerable untill I need to generate the actual dictionary.

Comment: Hm, sounds like you're better off with writing an enumerator that generates 200k GUIDs. You can easily do something like `myfunc(guid)` in the `ToDictionary` call.